# Getting depth map

Tags: opencv, stereo-3d, 3d-reconstruction, stereoscopy, disparity-mapping

I can't  get normal depth map from disparity. 
Here is my code:

```
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/calib3d/calib3d.hpp"
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include "opencv2/contrib/contrib.hpp"
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

ofstream out("points.txt");

int main()
{
    Mat img1, img2;
    img1 = imread("images/im7rect.bmp");
    img2 = imread("images/im8rect.bmp");

    //resize(img1, img1, Size(320, 280));
    //resize(img2, img2, Size(320, 280));

    Mat g1,g2, disp, disp8;
    cvtColor(img1, g1, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    cvtColor(img2, g2, CV_BGR2GRAY);

    int sadSize = 3;
    StereoSGBM sbm;
    sbm.SADWindowSize = sadSize;
    sbm.numberOfDisparities = 144;//144; 128
    sbm.preFilterCap = 10; //63
    sbm.minDisparity = 0; //-39; 0
    sbm.uniquenessRatio = 10;
    sbm.speckleWindowSize = 100;
    sbm.speckleRange = 32;
    sbm.disp12MaxDiff = 1;
    sbm.fullDP = true;
    sbm.P1 = sadSize*sadSize*4;
    sbm.P2 = sadSize*sadSize*32;
    sbm(g1, g2, disp);

    normalize(disp, disp8, 0, 255, CV_MINMAX, CV_8U);

    Mat dispSGBMscale; 
    disp.convertTo(dispSGBMscale,CV_32F, 1./16); 

    imshow("image", img1);

    imshow("disparity", disp8);

    Mat Q;
    FileStorage fs("Q.txt", FileStorage::READ);
    fs["Q"] >> Q;
    fs.release();

    Mat points, points1;
    //reprojectImageTo3D(disp, points, Q, true);
    reprojectImageTo3D(disp, points, Q, false, CV_32F);
    imshow("points", points);

    ofstream point_cloud_file;
    point_cloud_file.open ("point_cloud.xyz");
    for(int i = 0; i < points.rows; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < points.cols; j++) {
            Vec3f point = points.at<Vec3f>(i,j);
            if(point[2] < 10) {
                point_cloud_file << point[0] << " " << point[1] << " " << point[2]
                    << " " << static_cast<unsigned>(img1.at<uchar>(i,j)) << " " << static_cast<unsigned>(img1.at<uchar>(i,j)) << " " << static_cast<unsigned>(img1.at<uchar>(i,j)) << endl;
            }
        }
    }
    point_cloud_file.close(); 

    waitKey(0);

    return 0;
}
```

My images are:

[image]
[image]

Disparity map:

[image]

I get smth like this point cloud:
[image]

Q is equal: 
[ 1., 0., 0., -3.2883545303344727e+02, 0., 1., 0.,
       -2.3697290992736816e+02, 0., 0., 0., 5.4497170185417110e+02, 0.,
       0., -1.4446083962336606e-02, 0. ]

I tried many other things. I tried with different images, but no one is able to get normal depth map.

What am I doing wrong? Should I do with reprojectImageTo3D or use other approach instead of it? What is the best way to vizualize depth map? (I tried point_cloud library)
Or could you provide me the working example with dataset and calibration info, that I could run it and get depth map. Or how can I get depth_map from middlebury stereo database (http://vision.middlebury.edu/stereo/data/), I think there isn't enough calibration info.

Edited:
Now I get smth like :
[image]

It is of course better, but still not normal.

Edited2: 
I tried what you say:

```
Mat disp;
disp = imread("disparity-image.pgm", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);

Mat disp64; 
disp.convertTo(disp64,CV_64F, 1.0/16.0); 
imshow("disp", disp);
```

I get this result with line cv::minMaxIdx(...) :
[image]

And this when I comment this line:
[image]

Ps: Also please could you tell me how can I calculate depth knowing only baseline and focal length in pixels.

Comment: it all depends on your calibration. if you had an reprojection err of more than 0.5, you'll get a bad Q matrix

Comment: @berak: I know about it, and becasuse I could not obtain good calibration I tried it on dataset from internet (https://code.google.com/p/tjpstereovision/source/browse/) and I think it is normal Q matrix. How can I get depth map from middleburry dataset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have made a simple comparison between OpenCV's [`reprojectImageTo3D()`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#reprojectimageto3d) and my own (see below), and also run a test for a correct disparity and `Q` matrix.

```
// Reproject image to 3D
void customReproject(const cv::Mat& disparity, const cv::Mat& Q, cv::Mat& out3D)
{
    CV_Assert(disparity.type() == CV_32F && !disparity.empty());
    CV_Assert(Q.type() == CV_32F && Q.cols == 4 && Q.rows == 4);

    // 3-channel matrix for containing the reprojected 3D world coordinates
    out3D = cv::Mat::zeros(disparity.size(), CV_32FC3);

    // Getting the interesting parameters from Q, everything else is zero or one
    float Q03 = Q.at<float>(0, 3);
    float Q13 = Q.at<float>(1, 3);
    float Q23 = Q.at<float>(2, 3);
    float Q32 = Q.at<float>(3, 2);
    float Q33 = Q.at<float>(3, 3);

    // Transforming a single-channel disparity map to a 3-channel image representing a 3D surface
    for (int i = 0; i < disparity.rows; i++)
    {
        const float* disp_ptr = disparity.ptr<float>(i);
        cv::Vec3f* out3D_ptr = out3D.ptr<cv::Vec3f>(i);

        for (int j = 0; j < disparity.cols; j++)
        {
            const float pw = 1.0f / (disp_ptr[j] * Q32 + Q33);

            cv::Vec3f& point = out3D_ptr[j];
            point[0] = (static_cast<float>(j)+Q03) * pw;
            point[1] = (static_cast<float>(i)+Q13) * pw;
            point[2] = Q23 * pw;
        }
    }
}
```

Almost the same results were produced by both of the methods and they all seem correct to me. Would you please try it on your disparity map and `Q` matrix? You can have my test environment on my [GitHub](https://github.com/bkornel/Reproject-Image-To-3D).

**Note 1**: also take care to do not scale twice the disparity (comment out the line `disparity.convertTo(disparity, CV_32F, 1.0 / 16.0);` if your `disparity` was also scaled.)

**Note 2**: it was built with OpenCV 3.0, you may have to change the includes.

Comment: So `XYZ` is a 3-channel floating-point image of the same size as disparity. Each element of `XYZ` contains 3D coordinates of the point (x,y) computed from the disparity map. There was a misuse between your types and mine, I modified the code to use `double` everywhere.

Comment: Thanks, I edites question. I use Opencv 2.4.9. version

Comment: what happens if you comment out the line `cv::minMaxIdx(...)`?

Comment: Hard to tell [here](http://blog.martinperis.com/2012/01/3d-reconstruction-with-opencv-and-point.html) you have a sample code with a correct disparity and `Q` matrix, can you load and try it in your code?

Comment: I made a final test and the results seem correct to me, please see my updated answer

Comment: Yes it works, thank you very much for help :) I don't check with Opencv 3.0 I had no time yet, but I'll check it too.